# How to display elements in JSX based on OnChange of react-select element

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am new to react and self-taught, struggling with state and react-select

I have a dropdown with react-select. Depending on what value the user selects I want to display the relevant data onto the screen. The data is coming from the authContext(useContext). This is what I have written so far. But its not working. Can someone please guide me in the right direction:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import styles from './FullRecord.module.css'
import {AuthContext} from '../../shared/context/auth-context'
import Select from 'react-select'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    custom: {
      backgroundColor: "#558d6b",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    customFont: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: "20px"
    },
    customFont1: {
      fontWeight: "light"
    }
  });

const FullRecord = (props) => {

    const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
    const [tableValue, setTableValue] = useState(false)

    let data

    const options = auth.tournaments.map((tournament) => {
        return {
            value: tournament.TournamentName,
            label: tournament.TournamentName,
        }
    })
    
    const handleChange = (selectedValue) => {
        setSelectedValue(selectedValue);
        setTableValue(true)
        const {value}  = selectedValue
        let tname
        if(value === 'GSM Edition 1'){
            const noOfMatches = auth.profile.MemberMatches.filter((match) => match.TournamentName === 'GSM Edition 1')
            if(tableValue){
                return (
                    <div>
                 <li className={styles['member-item']}>
                     <Card className={classes.custom} variant="outlined">
                          <CardContent>
                               <Typography className={classes.customFont}  gutterBottom>
                                     Number Of Matches Played
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography className={classes.customFont}>
                                     {noOfMatches}
                                </Typography>
                           </CardContent>
                      </Card>
                 </li>               
            </div>
                )
            }            
        }
      }


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={styles['fullrecord__maindiv']}>
                <Select 
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 options={options}
                />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default FullRecord
```

Comment: add `console.log(selectedValue)` to the first line inside handleChange. What is logged when you select a value?

Comment: It shows me this {value: "GSM Edition 1", label: "GSM Edition 1"}, which is what I am expecting

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your first problem stems from using a function argument name that is the same as your state variable. Especially a problem as the function is also an arrow function.

```js
const handleChange = (newValue) => {
  setSelectedValue(newValue);
  setTableValue(true);
}
```

You're also trying to return JSX from your event handler, where it seems like what you really want is the core content to change when your selection changes. Ultimately, that logic goes in to your `FullRecord` return statement, and will automatically update as state is updated.

```js
const FullRecord = (props) => {
 // ...bunch of stuff, then
 return (
    <React.Fragment> {/* really don't need here, as you only have one root element */}
      <div className={styles['fullrecord__maindiv']}>
        <Select 
          onChange={handleChange}
          options={options}
        />
        {selectedValue ? (
          {/* output something here */}
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```